# Visualizing the flow of a constant vector field: shouldn't all the flow lines (integral curves) be in the same direction as the vector field?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-fields

A question in my text proposes the vector field $\vec v = x\vec j $. It shows that this:

[image]

as being the field itself; this makes sense. It also shows $\vec v $
's flow as being this:

[image]

Why is it that all the flow lines are in the same direction? Shouldn't the ones in quadrants $2$ and $3$, where $x$ is negative, be pointing/flowing downwards?

Comment: Yes, they should.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you.  The flow line through $(x_0,y_0)$ has equations $x(t) = x_0$, $y(t) = y_0 + x_0t$.

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" to this equation is, for each point $(a,b)$, a curve $\gamma_{ab}$ passing through $(a, b)$ at some time (I'll use $t = 0$) , and with 
$$
\gamma_{ab}'(t) = v(\gamma(a,b))
$$

So here's the solution:

$$
\gamma_{ab}(t) = (a, b) + t (a,0) = ((1+t)a,  b)
$$
Clearly $\gamma_{ab}(0) = (a, b)$, so it passes through the point.

What's $\gamma_{ab}'(t)$? It's just $(a, 0)$, which is exactly the vector field at location $(a, (1+t)b)$

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a bit lost in the notation here. I've not seen equations for vector fields or integral curves that don't explicitly mention $\hat i$ or $\hat j$. The solution $\gamma_{ab}(t) = (a, b) + t (a,0)$ , is that meaning to say that $\gamma_{ab}(t) = a\hat i +  (at + b)\hat j$, where $a,b$ are just constants? And is your conclusion that the visualization of the flow in my text is indeed correct (which disagrees with what other commenters have said)? Thank you for the help btw, appreciate it!

Comment: Using $i,j$ notation, I'd say that $\gamma'(t) = ai + bj$, and that $\gamma(t) = (1+t)ai + bj$. And I didn't say it, but I agree with the others -- your text's picture is simply wrong.